# Invalid login & problem registration password AccountController.php

Tags: database, controllers, login, customer-account, register

i have magento 1.9.1

I have some problem with registration and customer login.
In registration page i had some errors with the password field.

--ERROR

```
Cannot save the customer.
Invalid method Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::cleanPasswordsValidationData(Array ( ) )
```

So i have modified /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

```
if (empty($errors)) {
  // i have commented this line $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
```

**The registration of customer works but when i try to login it doesn't work.
I have the error that LOGIN AND PASSWORD ARE INVALID**

I have this error message with new accounts that i created, old accounts works.

How can i solve the problem?
It is a problem with magento eav attribute in database?

Comment: do you have the Customer model overwritten in local? Search for app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php If the file exists then it must have had some functions removed from it

Answer (score 3):

`cleanPasswordsValidationData()`is not a default method available in Magento. So I guess you have some customizations which are carried out in `AccountController.php` or there may be a rewrite for this very same class.

During customer registration, magento will execute `createPostAction()` method which is present in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`. If you inspect this method, you can't find a method with name `cleanPasswordsValidationData()` which is called up on a customer instance.

Even-though you comment it out the line which holds `cleanPasswordsValidationData()`, that line of code is intended to use some validation on posted data which is important in case of customer registration process. So instead of commenting it out, you need to dig from there and make the validation correct.

May be this customization is done during development of the site. Contact the developer if you are not a developer. That's the only possibility to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Rajeev isn't right. This is default Magento method for the `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` class for CE 1.9.1.

There are several possibilities:

1) Your core files were modified.

2) You have old version of that class in code/local/Mage which substitutes `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` and doesn't implement this method.

The method itself (CE 1.9.1 version):

```
/**
 * Clean password's validation data (password, password_confirmation)
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 */
public function cleanPasswordsValidationData()
{
    $this->setData('password', null);
    $this->setData('password_confirmation', null);
    return $this;
}
```